# How to keep subview, moved with pan gesture, in position after resigning keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have added an `ImageView` as a subview to a collection view in Swift. The initial point of this subview is laid out with anchor points in `viewDidLoad()`. However, after resigning the keyboard after a tap gesture in the view, the `ImageView` goes back to it's original position. How could I best solve this problem?

```
import UIKit

class MessageViewController: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

     let imageButton: UIImageView = {
         let imageButtonView = UIImageView()
         imageButtonView.image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
         imageButtonView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
         imageButtonView.layer.masksToBounds = true
         imageButtonView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
         return imageButtonView
     }()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         //add imageButton
         view.addSubview(imageButton)

     //        recognize tapgesture for removing keyboard
         let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(gesture:)))
         self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

         let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(gesture:)))
         imageButton.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
     }


    func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
            if let view = gesture.view {
                view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x, y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
  }


    imageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    imageButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    imageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

 }
```

Comment: Please share some code and visuals to help us better understand your question.

Comment: I added some code. Hope it will help to answer my question. This gives me an image that is in the middel of the screen once the view is loaded. Afterwards I can freely drag it around. However, only after resigning the keyboard the image goes back to its original position.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that after the keyboard is dismissed, `view.setNeedsLayout()` is called, which resets the constraints to their original positions.

Try this using only constraints, not adjusting the bounds (or center)

```
let imageCenterXConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
let imageCenterYConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //add imageButton
    view.addSubview(imageButton)

    //        recognize tapgesture for removing keyboard
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(gesture:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(gesture:)))
    imageButton.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    imageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    imageCenterXConstraint = imageButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    imageCenterXConstraint.isActive = true
    imageCenterYConstraint = imageButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 30)
    imageCenterYConstraint.isActive = true
    imageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
}

func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = gesture.view {
        imageCenterXConstraint.constant = translation.x
        imageCenterYConstraint.constant = 30 + translation.y
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it did not work for me. I will work on it and let you know if I have solved it.